# property getter or setter expected

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to use a bitmap var in a class. It makes 'property getter or setter expected' error. What is the problem?
The error shows around 'bmp? : Bitmap = null'.
How can I solve the problem?

And I don't understand why I must use getter or setter for private properties in a class.

```
class MyView(context: Context?) : View(context) {
    private var bmp? : Bitmap = null

    init {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawColor(Color.BLUE)
        canvas?.drawBitmap(bmp,10f,10f, null)
    }
}
```

Comment: use lateinit keyword while you init bitmap with null

Comment: If you want to create nullable Bitmap then use this syntax : `private var bmp : Bitmap? = null
`

Comment: use like this "lateinit var bmp : Bitmap"

Answer (score 9):

Issue is that you're going to create **Nullable** object using safe call operator, but your syntax is wrong. Inspite of placing **`?`** at variable, you'll need to put it at Reference type.

Check correct syntax :

```
private var bmp : Bitmap? = null
```

And then you can access this variable with safe call operator like below :

```
bmp?.someMethodCall() // This line will never throw you null pointer exception because of ? (Safe call operator)
```

Check out more **[here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).**

Answer (score 3):

Please try below line

```
lateinit var bmp : Bitmap
```